# Download box for saving files in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have earlier written jsp and html codes to upload a file from the hard disk into the database using

```
  <input type="file" name="upfile" >
```

But it opens a dialog box that has an "Open" button. What I need is a "Save" button that would download  a particular file to a given place in the hard disk, like what most browsers do on **Save** Option. Can anyone give the html codes as well as the jsp/javascript function that extracts the "download location" chosen by the user through the dialog box so as to save the file in that location. The task of saving the file is done through a java code in the backend.

Comment: You need your form to be `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - google it up and do some reading, it's not that complicated.

Comment: I have done that. That is not the problem. The point to understand is that enctype helps in uploading data which is different from downloading. Plus as stated I need a dialog box where there is a Save option not the regular Open option .

Comment: That's a simple form submit.

Comment: @alfasin: Can you tell me the html tag that opens a download box. And by downloading I mean storing some file from my database to the hard disk. How is it a simple form submit. Isn't form submission the other way round of what I need i.e. it stores data onto the database.

Comment: That's a form submit, the way I implemented it was uploading the file and saving it temporary on the server, and only then I attached it to the DB. The `file` button just let you choose the file, in order to upload it you need to submit the form.

Comment: @alfasin: let me clarify my question. I don't need to upload a file the way you are describing it. That is far too easy. I need to do something exactly the opposite of what you've mentioned above. I need to download i.e. save it from the server to the disk. Is it clear enough?

Comment: AFAIK the input type `file` is used only for upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't yo try using response.setContentType();
I think that can fulfill your requirement as it give user options about "Open File"/"Save File" you just have to know what particular type you have to write and that too you can know by using the request header. :-)
Here is a Servlet code that can be used to open/save Word File.

---

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class word extends HttpServlet
{
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse res)
    {
    res.setContentType("application/msword");
    try
    {
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        out.println("That's what I go to school for.. :-p ");

    }catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```

}